# c# local Cannot open database requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user MicrosoftAccount\(email)

Tags: c#, sql-server

Doesnt connect to database, its throw exception.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;InitialCatalog=CAFETERIADB;       Integrated Security=True;");
    SqlCommand cmd;
    SqlDataAdapter da;
    DataTable dt;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

 private void CashForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * FROM PhoneBook ORDER BY SLNo desc", con);
        dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 10;
        con.Close();

        comboBox1.Items.Clear();
        con.Open();
        cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Name FROM PhoneBook order by SLNo asc";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da1.Fill(dt);
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(dr["Name"].ToString());
        }
        con.Close();
```

here is my  connection string:

```
 <add name="CafeteriaDBConnectionString"
        connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\CafeteriaDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
```

Comment: Why give the `connectionString` from the config file when you don't use it?

Comment: Remove the AttachDbFilename from connection string.  It will give error when using Integrated Security=True.  Try opening up SQL Server Management Studio.  The instance of the database MSSQLLocalDB should match the login window of SSMS.  It should work with these correction.  The code posted has Data Source as a period which will not work because you are missing the instance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, place your connection string in single location. As on connection string inside code and second in configuration file.

```
     SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;InitialCatalog=CAFETERIADB;       Integrated Security=True;");
```

To make it working first test your connection string.

- Save notepad file as name.udl
- double click and provide appropriate values if local server (pc name \SQLEXPRESS) or (.\SQLEXPRESS)
- Click test and again open same udl file in notepad
- copy the connection string it will be some thing like below but exclude provider part
  Password=***;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=***;Initial Catalog=CafeteriaDB;Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS

```
     
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Password=***;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=***;Initial Catalog=CafeteriaDB;Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;")
```

I hope this will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think in your code you are referring to the connection string you set up in config file. Instead, you hard-coded a new connection in the first line of your code.

If you are sure the connection string in config file works fine, you can put it into your code directly.

Change your first line code as:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\CafeteriaDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
```

Or you can refer to connection string in config file.

```
  string connectionString = DatabaseHelper.CafeteriaDBConnectionString;
  SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
```